# Why is ec2_ami complaining about unknown parameter WaiterConfig?

Tags: ansible, ec2-ami

I am trying to use Ansible's ec2_ami module to create an AMI from an EC2 instance. To do this, I am running this role:

```
---
- name: Stop instance
  ec2:
    instance_id: "{{ instanceId }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    state: stopped
    wait: yes

- name: Create AMI
  ec2_ami:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    instance_id: "{{ instanceId }}"
    name: "{{ asg_name }}-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 | regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '-') }}"
    wait: yes
    state: present
  register: ami
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_zO2i0P/ansible_module_ec2_ami.py", line 701, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_zO2i0P/ansible_module_ec2_ami.py", line 697, in main
    create_image(module, connection)
  File "/tmp/ansible_zO2i0P/ansible_module_ec2_ami.py", line 470, in create_image
    waiter.wait(ImageIds=[image_id], WaiterConfig=dict(Delay=delay, MaxAttempts=max_attempts))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 53, in wait
    Waiter.wait(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 295, in wait
    response = self._operation_method(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self._client_method(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 470, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 523, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 270, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "WaiterConfig", must be one of: DryRun, ImageIds, Owners, ExecutableUsers, Filters
```

I am on linux Ubuntu 14.04 running Ansible version 2.5.0. These are the boto modules I have installed:

```
boto==2.45.0
boto3==1.7.0
botocore==1.4.50
```

I'm guessing I have a version problem but I'm not sure what it is. This role was running previously but I upgraded Ansible from version 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that botocore was in need of an upgrade.

```
sudo pip install awscli botocore boto3 -U
```

Now my boto versions are

```
boto==2.45.0
boto3==1.7.0
botocore==1.10.0
```

And the role is running fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have told the task to NOT wait

```
# CREATE THE AMI IMAGE
- name: Create AMI Image from the instance just created
  local_action:
    module: ec2_ami
    instance_id: "{{ ec2_id }}"
    wait: no
```

and the "waiterconfig" error message went away.

If you want to check on the progress of the AMI image creation, because you are no longer waiting in the task:

```
- name: Check the created AMI Image exists
  local_action:    
    module: ec2_ami_facts
    owners: self
    region: "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_akey }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_skey }}"        
    filters:
        "tag:Name": "NameOfAMI"
        "tag:ami_completeness": "someOtherTag"
  register: ami_find
  until: ami_find.images|length > 0
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

This will check every 10 seconds, for 5 goes, to see if an AMI turns up in the results. If there is 1, then the length is greater than 0. You need to be very specific in your filter so that there is ONLY ever one result, once the ami is created.

Comment: My script has later steps that depend on the AMI's creation being complete so this is not an option for me.

Comment: add a ec2_ami_facts checker straight underneath

Answer (score 1):

On Ansible 2.5, following the instructions about updating awscli, boto3 and botocore and the issue is still present.

```
TASK [Create AMI Image from the instance just created] ***********************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: Unknown parameter in input: "WaiterConfig", must be one of: DryRun, ImageIds, Owners, ExecutableUsers, Filters
fatal: [a_flap_prod_door_21841_a -> localhost]: FAILED!
```

pip modules

```
 - awscli==1.15.2
 - boto==2.48.0 
 - boto3==1.7.2 
 - botocore==1.10.2
```

The AMI gets created, but none of the tags. This wasn't an issue on Ansible 2.4.

This can be solved by telling the task to NOT wait:

```
# CREATE THE AMI IMAGE
- name: Create AMI Image from the instance just created
  local_action:
    module: ec2_ami
    instance_id: "{{ ec2_id }}"
    wait: no
```

and it's run through - no errors and the tags have been created

Comment: Happy for this post to be deleted in light of a slightly more succinct answer below. I have, however, clarified that installing the extra pip modules did NOT help and have found a work around of NOT waiting for the ami creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an issue with Ansible 2.5. Here is the bug report on GitHub: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/40303

You can either apply the workaround posted in other answers, or just go back to the 2.4 branch until the issue is resolved:

```
pip install ansible==2.4.5
```

This will remove your current Ansible version and install version 2.4.5 instead.

Note that at the time of writing, the 2.4.5 is the latest version on the 2.4 branch. You might want to look up the latest version in the [Ansible 2.4 Changelog](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/CHANGELOG.md) and install that instead.